# cmd window always open when I open my .exe application

Tags: python, cmd, auto-py-to-exe

I finished my python application and I converted it to .exe
but when I open the .exe file, I found that the cmd window is also open with the application window.
I used python3.10 and tkinter
also used auto-py-to-exe to convert

Comment: There is an option to hide the console within auto-py-to-exe. I suppose it is called `--windowed`  or `--noconsole` on the code

Answer (score 0):

You can add the --noconsole tag to the command when creating the .exe
`pyinstaller "other tags" --noconsole app.py`

Answer (score 0):

Use win32gui and win32con modules, installing it by pip install

```
import win32gui, win32con

the_program_to_hide =  win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() 
win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide , win32con.SW_HIDE
```

Answer (score 0):

1. open your `main.spec` file in text editor.
2. change `Console=True` to `Console=False`

[image: like this]

Comment: If you can add the code here, spare the image.